# Isolated scope on elements with multiple directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, scope, angularjs-scope

Long story short, I have a directive that does permission checks by an attribute on the element using the directive a simple example:

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/suunyz3e/285/

```
app.directive('test', function() {    
    return {        
        restrict : 'A',
        scope : true,
        controllerAs : '$ctrl',
        bindToController : true,
        controller : function($attrs) {
            this.test = $attrs.test || '';
        }
    };
});
```

The above simply uses the attribute test from the element and binds it to the controller.

This works fine for these values:

```
<div test="v">{{$ctrl | json }}</div>
<div test="va">{{$ctrl | json }}</div>
<div test="vb">{{$ctrl | json }}</div>
<div test="vc">{{$ctrl | json }}</div>
```

However, adding the same attribute to an existing element that has an isolated scope already, will trigger an error. So setting `scope: false` on the directive will obviously turn off the isolated scope, however this will just set all 4 elements to the last directive used, it will also inherit scope. `vc` is the value for all 4.

A very simple solution would be to wrap the element in another div an add the attribute to it, however sometimes it's not possible.

Is there a way to store the data on the element, and retrieve it with an angular expression without having an isolated scope, yet each element's data should still be isolated?

Comment: "However, adding the same attribute to an existing element that has an isolated scope already, will trigger an error." sorry but can you show some example for that ?

Comment: @nitz, copy the test directive, call it test2, make element `<div test="" test2=""></div>` it will raise an error as there's two directives asking for an isolated scope.